# Compare Two Dataframe columns

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

I have a dataframe like below.

```
A  B
1  2
2  1
3  4
```

I would like to compare each and every value from column A with all the values of column B and return True if it appears at least once or False if it doesn't exist in column C like below

```
A  B  C
1  2  True
2  1  True
3  4  False
```

I have tried with **filter(function, iterable)** but getting the below error.

```
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Any other ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: `df['C'] = df['A'].isin(df['B'].unique())` ?

Comment: Worked. Thank You :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic is not clear under what condition to return True or False anyways let us assume you want to return True for each value in a appears in b:

```
A = df['A'].tolist()
B = df['B'].tolist()
C = [(a in B) for a in A]
```

Comment: Logic is to check if A == B. But the given code only compares adjacent values, not the whole column. I would like to check if the value from column A is available in whole column B or not.

Comment: Guys, Is there a way to return the value itself instead of True/False? I need to append the values of column A to column C when the condition returns False.

Comment: C = [a if (a in B) for a in A]

Comment: It says 'else' expected. and throws SyntaxError.